# Why do I get a segmentation fault after a pointer assignment?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I got a segmentation fault when invoked a function immediately following a pointer assignment.

```
typedef struct
{
   DMINT field1;
   DMINT field2;
   DMINT field3;
} MSG1;

typedef struct
{
....
} MSG;

/* MSG is size of 1040 byte, bigger than MSG1 in size */

int main()
{
    MSG     Msg;
    MSG1   *pMsg1;
    int     mid;
    pthread_t  tid;
    ...

    Recv_msg( mid, &Msg);   /* this function does a memcpy to &Msg */
    pMsg1 = (MSG1 *)&Msg;

    //ret = pthread_join(pMsg1->..... );    /* Got Segmentation fault here by GDB*/
    /* even the first argument has nothing to do with pMsg1, SEGV is still received */
     ret = pthread_creat(&tid, NULL, thread_function, NULL); /* Got Segmentation fault here by GDB*/
```

It works fine if I remove `pMsg1 = (MSG1 *)&Msg`.
Is it because the two pointers have different sizes?

Comment: You should provide a little more information. E.g: what are you doing in `Recv_msg`? Source code please.

Comment: show much more code. Ensure that all pointers (including those inside structures) are initialized, and are not `NULL` when dereferenced. Consider also using `valgrind` to chase memory leaks bugs.

Comment: You need much more information for others to even begin to diagnose this.

Comment: pthread_join() takes thread id as the first argument. Are you sure that pMsg1->... is a real thread id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely convert one struct pointer to another **only if one struct lays in the beginning of another** (no matter sizes they are, see C std.):

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
} S1;
typedef struct {
  S1 s1; // <- s1 it the FIRST structure field
  int b;
} S2;
S2 s2;
S1 *s1;
s1= (S1*)&s2; // <- safe
```

Otherwise you could get into aligning issues and undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`MSG1` and `MSG` are different types.

`pMsg1` is pointing to `Msg`, which is of type `MSG`, but it is of type `MSG1*`.

When trying to access fields from `MSG1`, in a memory area where a `MSG` lays, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Why would that cause a segfault though?  It's still a valid pointer address.

Comment: It causes a segfault because `pthread_join` tries to make sense of the data it finds at that address, but it's nonsense.

Comment: It's not segfaulting on the pointer assignment though. Its segfaulting when you access 'pMsg1->' in the call to pthread_join()

Comment: If one wants to byte-wise access to an integer or any other data type, the pointer to the data object can be type-casted to char *. 

I think, type-casting MSG pointer to MSG1 pointer in order to access MSG1 length of MSG at a time, is allowed....

Comment: ALL: We have no idea what is the `sizeof(DMINT)` and as a result what is the `sizeof(MSG)`, It might be that it is extremely large and exedes the program size itself - to an unallocated area, and the OS will cause segfault. It might not be the case, but without more data - there are dozens of reason why it could fail, all based on the fact that `pMSG1` is pointing to a `MSG`

Comment: The question has the following details:
size of MSG is 1040 Bytes and sizeof(MSG1) < sizeof(MSG).

Comment: @Mallik: True, missed it. so it is not that issue, it could still be the pthread() issue, or some inner access in the `...` part in the segfaulting line.

Answer (score 0):

If the structures are not identical then do not copy by assigning

```
 pMsg1 = (MSG1 *)&Msg;
```

copy the structures individual elements. Then it solves u r issue.